# List of US universities in English and Chinese

Tags: word-requests

Does anyone know where to get a list of US universities in both chinese and english?

Comment: This question seems a little too broad, there are thousands of US universities there. You may want to narrow your scope

Comment: I would be happy with several hundred or a few thousand. The bigger the list, the more happy I am.

Comment: This is not how you use this site. Sorry downvoted.

Comment: You didn't even mark James Wu's answer as correct and even asked him for a CSV version. You're asking ppl here to make your work.

Answer (score 8):

just can list some famous universities as below:

```
1. Adelphi University 亞狄非大學
2. American University 美國大學
3. Arizona State University 亞利桑那州立大學
4. Andrews University 安德魯斯大學
5. Boston University 波士頓大學
6. Biola University 比奧拉大學
7. Baylor University 貝勒大學
8. Ball State University 鮑爾州立大學
9. Duke University 杜克大學
10. Drexel University 德雷塞爾大學
11. DePaul University 德寶大學
12. Colorado State University 科羅拉多州立大學
13. Colorado School of Mines 科羅拉多礦學院
14. College of William and Mary 威廉與瑪麗學院
15. Cleveland State University 克利夫蘭州立大學
16. Clemson University 克萊姆森大學
17. Clarkson University 克拉遜大學
18. Clark University 克拉克大學
19. Carnegie-Mellon University 卡內基美隆大學
20. Brown University 布朗大學
21. Brigham Young University 楊百翰大學
22. Brandeis University 布蘭迪斯大學
23. Bowling Green State University 鮑靈格林大學
24. Duquesne University 迪尤肯大學
25. Emory University 艾摩雷大學
26. Florida Atlantic University 佛羅里達大西洋大學
27. Florida Institute of Technology 佛羅里達科技大學
28. Florida International University 佛州國際大學
29. Florida State University 佛羅里達州立大學
30. George Mason University 喬治梅森大學
31. George Washington University 喬治華盛頓大學
32. Georgetown University 喬治敦大學
33. Georgia State University 佐治亞州立大學
34. Howard University 霍華德大學
35. Idaho State University 愛達荷州立大學
36. Illinois State University 伊利諾州立大學
37. Illionis Institute of Technology 伊利諾理工學院
38. Indiana State University 印第安納州立大學
39. Indiana University of Pennsylvania 賓州印第安納大學
40. Indiana University Bloomington 印第安納布盧明頓大學
41. Iowa State University of Science And Technology 依阿華州立大學
42. John F. Kennedy University 約翰.肯尼迪大學
43. Kansas State University 堪薩斯州立大學
44. Kent State University 肯特州立大學
45. La Sierra University 拉西拉大學
46. Loma Linda University 洛瑪連達大學
47. Lehigh University 利哈伊大學
48. Louisiana State University, Baton Rouge 路易斯安那州立大學
49. Louisiana Tech University 路易斯安那理工大學
50. Loyola University of Chicago 萊奧那芝加哥大學
51. Marquette University 馬奎特大學
52. Massachusetts Institute of Technology 麻省理工學院
53. Miami University, Oxford 邁阿密大學
54. Michigan State University 密執安州立大學
55. Michigan Technological University 密執安理工大學
56. Middle Tennessee State University 中田納西州州立大學
57. Mississippi State University 密西西比州立大學
58. Montana State University 蒙大拿州立大學
59. National Hispanic University 西班牙語裔國民大學
60. Naval Postgraduate School 海軍研究生院
61. New College of California 加利福尼亞新學院
62. New Jersey Institute of Technology 新澤西理工學院
63. New Mexico State University 新墨西哥州立大學
64. New school for Social Research 社會研究新學院
65. New York University 紐約大學
66. North Carlonia State University ay Raleigh 北卡羅來納州立大學
67. North Dakota State University 北達科他州立大學
68. Northeastern University 東北大學
69. Northern Illinois University 北伊利諾伊大學
70. Northwestern University 西北大學
71. Nova Southeastern University 諾瓦東南大學
72. Ohio State University 俄亥俄州立大學
73. Ohio University 俄亥俄大學
74. Oklahoma State University 俄克拉荷馬州立大學
75. Old Dominion University 奧多明尼昂大學
76. Oregon State University 俄勒岡州立大學
77. Pace University 佩斯大學
78. Pacific Union College 太平洋聯合大學
79. Pennsylvania State University 賓州州立大學
80. Pepperdine University 佩波戴恩大學
81. Pepperdine Univrsity 佩普丁大學
82. Pittsburg State University 匹茲堡州立大學
83. Polytechnic University 理工大學
84. Portland State University 波特蘭州立大學
85. princeton university 普林斯頓大學
86. Purdue University 珀杜大學
87. Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute 倫斯萊爾科技學院
88. Rice University 萊斯大學
89. Rutgers at New Brunswick 拉傑斯大學
90. SCHILLER INTERNATIONAL UNIVERSITY 席勒國際大學
91. Seton Hall University 薛頓賀爾大學
92. Southern Illinois University at Carbondale 南伊利諾伊卡本代爾大學
93. Southern Methodist University 南衛理工會大學
94. St.John's University 聖約翰大學
95. st.Louis University 聖路易斯大學
96. Stanford University 斯坦福大學(史丹福)
97. Stevens Institute of Technology 史蒂文斯科技學院
98. SUNY at Albany 紐約州立奧爾巴尼大學
99. SUNY at Binghamton 紐約州立賓漢姆頓大學
100. SUNY at Stony Brook 紐約州立石溪大學
101. SUNY at Buffalo 紐約州立水牛城大學
102. Syracuse University 雪城大學
103. CHRISTCHURCH POLYTECHNIC 基督城理工學院
104. The johns Hopkins university 約翰霍普金斯大學
105. The University of Akron 阿克倫大學
106. The University of Texas at Arlington 德州阿靈頓大學
107. Thomas Aquinas College 托馬斯阿奎那斯學院
108. Tufts University 塔夫脫大學
109. Tulane University 杜倫大學
110. Tulane University 圖蘭大學
111. United States International University 美國國際大學
112. Univ. Of North Carolina-Chapel Hill 北卡羅來納-教堂山大學
113. Univerity of North Carolina at Greensboro 北卡羅來納格林斯伯勒大學
114. University of Alabama at Birmingham 阿拉巴馬伯明翰大學
115. University of Alaska 阿拉斯加大學
116. University of Arkansas 阿肯色大學
117. Tennessee State Univerity 田納西州立大學
118. Texas A&M University 德克薩斯州A＆M大學
119. Texas Christian University 德州基督教大學
120. Texas Southern Univrsity 南德州大學
121. Texas Tech University 德州理工大學
122. Texas Woman's University 德州女子大學
123. The Catholic University of America 美國天主教大學
124. University of California at Berkeley 加州柏克萊大學
125. University of California at Los Angeles 加州洛衫磯大學
126. University of California at Santa Cruz 加州聖克魯斯大學
127. University of California, Davis 加州戴維斯大學
128. University of California, Riverside 加州河畔大學
129. University of California, San Diego 加州聖迭戈大學(加州聖地牙哥)
130. University of California, Santa Barbara 加州聖芭芭拉大學
131. University of California-Irvine 加州伊榮大學
132. University of Central Florida 中佛羅里達大學
133. University of Chicago 芝加哥大學
134. University of Cincinnati 辛辛那提大學
135. University of Colorado at Boulder 科羅拉多博爾德大學
136. University of Connecticut at Storrs 康涅狄格斯托斯大學
137. University of Delaware 特拉華大學
138. University of Denver 丹佛大學
139. University of Florida 佛羅里達大學
140. University of Georgia 佐治亞大學
141. University of Hawaii at Manoa 夏威夷馬諾大學
142. University of Huston 休斯頓大學
143. University of Idaho 愛達荷大學
144. University of Illinois，Urbana－Champaign 伊利諾伊大學
145. University of Iowa 依阿華大學
146. University of Kansas 堪薩斯大學
147. University of Kentucky 肯塔基大學
148. University of La Verne 加州拉文大學
149. University of Louisville 路易斯維爾大學
150. University of Maine at Orono 緬因州奧羅諾大學
151. University of Maryland 馬里蘭大學
152. University of Massachusetts at Amherst 阿默斯特大學
153. University of Massachusetts at Lowell 盧維爾大學
154. University of Memphis 孟菲斯大學
155. University of Minnesota，Twin Cities 明尼蘇達雙城大學
156. University of Mississippi 密西西比大學
157. University of Missouri, Columbia 密蘇里哥倫比亞大學
158. University of Missouri/Kansas City 密蘇里堪薩斯大學
159. University of Montana 蒙大拿大學
160. University of Nebraska at Lincoln 內布拉斯加林肯大學
161. University of Nevada, Reno 內華達裡諾大學
162. University of New Hampshire 新罕布什爾大學
163. University of New Mexico at Main Campus 新墨西哥大學
164. University of New Orleans 新奧爾良大學
165. University of North Dakota 北達科他大學
166. University of North Texas 北德州大學
167. University of Northern Colorado 北科羅拉多大學
168. University of Notre Dame 聖母大學
169. University of Oklahoma 俄克拉荷馬大學
170. University of Oregon 俄勒岡大學
171. University of Pennsylvania 賓夕法尼亞大學
172. University of Pittsburgh 匹茲堡大學
173. University of Rhode Island 羅德島大學
174. University of San Diego 聖迭戈大學(聖地牙哥)
175. University of San Franciso 舊金山大學
176. University of South Carolina at Columbia 南卡羅來納哥倫比亞大學
177. University of Southern California 南加利福尼亞大學
178. University of South Dakota 南達科他大學
179. University of Southern Mississippi 南密西西比大學
180. University of Southwestern Louisiana 西南路易斯安那大學
181. University of Texas at Dallas 德州達拉斯大學
182. University of Texas-Austin 德州大學奧斯汀分校
183. University of the Pacific 太平洋大學
184. University of Toledo 托萊多大學
185. University of Tulsa 塔爾薩大學
186. University of Utah 猶他大學
187. University of Vermont 佛蒙特大學
188. University of Virginia 弗吉尼亞大學
189. University of Washington 西雅圖華盛頓大學
190. University of Wisconsin，Milwaukee 米爾沃基大學(密爾瓦基)
191. University of Wisconsin-Madison 威斯康星大學麥迪遜分校
192. University of Wyoming 懷俄明大學
193. University ofTennessee, Knoxville 諾斯維爾田納西大學
194. Univresity of Arizona 亞利桑那大學
195. Utah State University 猶他州立大學
196. Vanderbilt University 范德比大學
197. Virginia Tech 弗吉尼亞科技大學
198. Wake Forest University 威克森林大學
199. Washington State University 華盛頓州立大學
200. Washington University 華盛頓大學
201. Wayne State University 韋恩州立大學
202. West Virginia University 西弗吉尼亞大學
203. Western Michigan University 西密執安大學
204. Wichita State University 維奇托州立大學
205. Woodbury University 伍德布里大學
206. Worcester Polytechnic Institute 伍斯特科技學院
207. Wright State University 萊特州立大學
208. Yale University 耶魯大學
209. Yeshiva University 耶希華大學
210. Georgia Institute of Technology 喬治亞理工學院
211. Harvard University 哈佛大學
212. Occidental College 西方學院
213. The Wharton Business School 沃頓商學院
214. VALLEY FORGE MILITARY ACADAMY AND COLLEGE 美國翠谷軍校
215. UNIVERSITY OF MICHIGAN 密歇根大學
216. Art Institute of Atlanta 亞特蘭大(Atlanta)藝術學院
217. Art Institute of Dallas 達拉斯藝術學院
218. Art Institute of Fort Lauderdale 弗特勞德達爾藝術學院
219. Art Institute of Houston 休斯頓藝術學院
220. Art Institute of Los Angeles 洛杉磯藝術學院
221. Art Institute of Colorado 科羅拉多藝術學院
222. Art Institute of Philadelphia 費城（Philadelphia）藝術學院
223. Art Institute of Phoenix 鳳凰藝術學院
224. Art Institute of Pittsburgh 匹茲堡（Pittsburgh）藝術學院
225. Art Institute of Seattle 西雅圖藝術學院
226. Art Institute of Portland 波特蘭藝術學院
227. Art Institutes International at San Francisco 舊金山國際藝術學院
228. Art Institute of California 加里福尼亞藝術學院
229. California State University-Stanislaus 加州州立大學-斯坦尼斯勞斯分校
230. Embry-Riddle Aeronautical University 艾姆伯裡-利德爾航空學院
231. Illinois Institute of Art Chicago 伊利諾斯芝加哥藝術學院
232. BUENA VISTA UNIVERSITY 比尤納維斯特大學
233. AMERICAN UNIVERSITY 美利堅大學
234. BERRY COLLEGE 貝里學院
235. AGNES SCOTT COLLEGE 阿格尼斯?斯科特學院
236. BETHEL COLLEGE 貝塞爾學院
237. RICE UNIVERSITY 賴斯大學
238. BELLARMINE COLLEGE 貝拉明學院
239. BARD COLLEGE 巴德學院
240. ALLEGHENY COLLEGE 阿勒格尼學院
241. BENNINGTON COLLEGE 本寧頓學院
242. BOWDOIN COLLEGE 鮑登學院
243. COLLEGE OF THE ATLANTIC 大西洋學院
244. BALDWIN-WALLACE COLLEGE 鮑德溫—華萊士學院
245. ALBION COLLEGE 阿爾比恩學院
246. ECKERD COLLEGE 埃克德學院
247. ST. JOHN'S UNIVERSITY 聖瓊斯大學
248. ALBERTSON COLLEGE OF IDAHO 愛達荷艾伯森學院
249. ALBRIGHT COLLEGE 奧爾布賴特學院
250. FRANKLIN AND MARSHALL COLLEGE 富蘭克林與馬歇爾學院
251. AUGUSTANA COLLEGE 奧古斯塔那學院
252. BIRMINGHAM-SOUTHERN COLLEGE 伯明翰-南方學院
253. EARLHAM COLLEGE 厄勒姆學院
254. JOHNS HOPKINS UNIVERSITY 約翰霍普金斯大學
255. COLLEGE OF WILLIAMS AND MARY 威廉姆瑪麗亞大學
256. UNIVERSITY OF SOUTH FLORIDA 南佛羅里達大學
257. LOUISIANA STATE UNIVERSITY-BATON ROUGE 路易斯安那州立大學巴頓汝之分校
258. OLD DOMINION UNIVERSITY 多米尼恩大學
259. BRADLEY UNIVERSITY 布拉德利大學
260. Dickson State University 狄克森州立大學  
261. Stanford Graduate School of Business 美國斯坦福商學院
262. Southern New Hampshair University 南新罕布什爾大學
263. Johns Hopkins University 約翰-霍普金斯大學
```

Comment: Hey James, this is a great list. Do you have a csv or xls file?